# Optimal model structure for a Django-driven spare parts website

Tags: django, inheritance, model

I am developing a website on Django for a spare parts distributor. Besides several additional tables (brands, models, countries, etc.), the main subject are spare parts themselves. My question is what would be the proper database structure for spare parts.

The matter is that some characteristics are common between all spare parts (id, article, price, brand, compatibility or car model, etc.) while some other are specific for a category. For example, for a leaf spring, the number of plates is important, and for a petrol tank it is the volume in litres.

I can see three options with different *pro* and *contra*:

1. One table for all spare parts. The table has all fields and all categories, but many of them are empty.
2. Multi-table inheritance. There is one common model "Part" and many models inherited from it, one table for each category (PetrolTank, Radiator, etc.). This is most logical, but the number of tables can potentially be great (~ no. of categories). The great number of models in one application is not recommended (for example by the nice book "Two scoops of Django").
3. Proxy models. All parts are kept in one table, which has all fields, many of them inevitably empty. But we create a number of proxy models for every category, and deal with them as there were completely different models.

I decline one other solution - independent tables (models) one for each category, because it has many drawbacks (for example, it will not be able to select or filter spare parts by all tables, for instance, all parts for Toyota), and I don't see any benefits in it.

What you advice me, which option from the above three is the best, in your opinion? I most like the number 2, but proxy models are also promising. Or perhaps there are other options which I haven't thought about?

Comment: Is the number of categories fixed and known? Because if not, then you probably need to make it easy to add new categories, which may preclude the idea of granting each category its own table (because then you'd have to change code to add a category). So you're back to using just one table. Have you considered using something like a [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#jsonfield) to condense the "optional fields"?

Comment: The number of categories is not firmly fixed. And I'm inclining to using one table, too. Possibly, will be using proxy models for different categories. Most of sources strictly discourage the use of multi-table inheritance, because each request would affect several tables. Thanks for the advice on JSONfield, I'm to study this matte.